# Create list with unique properties of items in Groovy

Tags: groovy

For example I have such domain class:

```
class PaymentSystems {
    String paymentSystemName
    long bill
    boolean enabled = true

    static belongsTo = [cafee: Cafee]

    static constraints = {
        bill nullable: true
        cafee nullable: true
    }
}
```

This string can return an unique list of items:

```
def paymentSystems = PaymentSystems.list().unique()
```

But I want to create unique list relay on, for example, on paymentSystemName - property, i.e. I want to get list with unique paymentSystemName-property. How to do this?

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the [docs](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/util/Collection.html#unique()) `unique` uses default comparator. You need to implement it in the `PaymentSystems` class or pass as an argument `unique` invocation.